# How to export date to excel file using DataTables ExcelHtml5

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, excel, datatables

I am currently using DataTables jquery plugin (https://datatables.net/) to create a table with date filters and column sorting that can be exported to an excel file.

The datatable export buttons allow you to set an attribute called `messageTop` that will display a message above the data in the export (https://datatables.net/reference/button/excelHtml5)

The date range filters are set using two `<input>` tags with the ids `min` and `max`. I am trying to pass these date values to the exported excel file so that I can display the date range using `messageTop` as you can see below:

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function() {

      // Custom filtering function which will search data in column four between two values
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
        function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
            var min = minDate.val();
            var max = maxDate.val();
            // data[1] is the date column
            var date = new Date( data[1] );
     
            if (
                ( min === null && max === null ) ||
                ( min === null && date <= max ) ||
                ( min <= date   && max === null ) ||
                ( min <= date   && date <= max )
            ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );

      // Refilter the table
      $('#min, #max').on('change', function () {
          table.draw();
      });


    // Create date inputs
      minDate = new DateTime($('#min'), {
          format: 'MMMM Do YYYY'
      });
      maxDate = new DateTime($('#max'), {
          format: 'MMMM Do YYYY'
      });

      var table = $('#invoicetable').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
              extend: 'excelhtml5',
              messageTop: 'Invoice Period: ' + minDate.val()  + ' to ' + maxDate.val()
            }
        ]
      } );
  } ); 
</script>
```

The issue is that `minDate.val()` and `maxDate.val()` are just being displayed as `null` in the exported excel file. If I do `console.log(minDate.val())` right above the table instantiation it still gives a null value, but if I try to access the `<input>` element from the function that refilters the table I can access the dates in the input fields.

It seems that the problem is that when I try and use the values of the date inputs in the table instantiation it is just using the values from when the page is first loaded and the inputs are still empty. How would I go about exporting the current date inputs after the user has entered some value?

For reference here is my html code:

```
           <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Start Date:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" id="min" name="min"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>End Date:</td>
                  <td><input type="text" id="max" name="max"></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

            <table class="table" id="invoicetable">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">Invoice #</th>
                <th scope="col">Invoice Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Customer Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Invoice Amount</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>

              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2021-12-21</td>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>100</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem required using a function in `messageTop` so that it is run each time the button is clicked, therefore getting the current values of the input fields.

```
messageTop: function() {
   return 'Invoice Period: ' + String(minDate.val())  + ' to ' + String(maxDate.val());
},
```

The previous way I tried to accomplish this resulted in `messageTop` being statically defined and only contained the null values of the inputs before anything was entered.